# Python code for multiple PIR motion sensors on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

Connecting up to three 5v motion sensors on the raspberry pi for a project and I'm pretty new to python. I've successfully coded one motion sensor which lights up an LED and makes a buzzer sound when motion detected. How would I code multiple sensors that then light up different LEDs?

```
# Motion detected with buzzer and LED

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

#Refer pins by their sequence number on the board
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

#Read output from PIR motion sensor
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN)

#LED output pin
GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT)

while True:
    inp = GPIO.input(18)
#When output from motion sensor is HIGH
    if inp == 1:
    print("Motion detected!!")
    GPIO.output(3, 1) #Turn on LED & Buzzer
    time.sleep(1)

#When output from motion sensor in LOW
    elif inp == 0:
    print("No motion, all okay.")
    GPIO.output(3, 0) #Turn off LED & Buzzer
    time.sleep(1)

time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Have you tried repeating the setup process for a second sensor and adding corresponding checks in the while-loop?

Comment: This code can't work. Indentation after "if" and "elif" is missing!

Comment: Oops, I messed the indent up when putting the code on this. Indent is okay on actual code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create different instances for your sensors, for instance

```
inp_a = GPIO.input(18)
inp_b = GPIO.input(1x)
```

and so on.

then you can check with

```
if inp_b == 1
```

You can implement multithreading as well

Also, note that your last line of code, after the while loop, will never be executed.

Comment: Do I put the new if statement with 'inp_b' in a new while loop?

Comment: You can use a second while loop only if you use multi-treading, otherwise you can't have to "while True" loops running at the same time.

Comment: If you want to keep things simple, you should do everything in the same while loop

Answer (score 0):

If anyone in the future is looking to use a pair of PIR motion sensors on a raspberry 4, this code above helped me figured it out. The code below is how i used it.

```
motion_1 = GPIO.add_event_detect(pirPin, GPIO.RISING, callback=LIGHTS)
motion_2 = GPIO.add_event_detect(pirPin2, GPIO.RISING, callback=LIGHTS2)                                                                                                                                                                            

try:
    while True:
          if motion_1 == 1:
              motion_1
              print('Test for BTC') # print in command line , not LCD
              time.sleep(1)
          elif motion_2 == 1:
              motion_2
              print('Test for eth') # print in command line, not LCD
              time.sleep(1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Quit')
    GPIO.cleanup()

 ## the lights function being called above, pulls data from binance API, and prints out the price to an LCD screen, so i can trigger a PIR motion on the left and it returns BTC, i can trigger PIR motion on the right and it returns ETH prices. Kind of fun to build.
```